# Groovy Binding: rebind value

Tags: binding, groovy, immutability

I have an application in which some of configurations are stored in database and upon launching they are being injected into config object.
The way they're stored are in `object path` string like: `"some.config.value"`.

So after parsing it becomes into this kind of map:
`[some: [config: [value: [:]]]]`

I achieved this using [`Binding`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html), here is the code:

```
Binding bind = new Binding()
bind.tmp = bean // Bean is an object where it is being injected

String[] traverse = stringPath.split(/\./)
def shift = bind.tmp
traverse.eachWithIndex { String it, int i ->
    if (it) {
        if (!(shift instanceof Map)) {
            shift = ["$it": [:]] // <-- Doesn't work
        } else {
            if (!shift?.containsKey(it)) {
                // val - is a value to assign to last key in path
                shift[it] = (i + 1 == traverse.size()) ? val : [:]
            } else if (shift?.containsKey(it) && (i + 1 == traverse.size())) {
                shift[it] = val
            }
        }

        shift = shift[it]
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if I have already defined key in binding, I cannot seem to re-define it (in `shift = ["$it": [:]]`).

e.g.: if I have `config.val` and `config.val.moreConfig` - then `moreConfig` will not be assigned.

After sometime I just decided to assign values by declaring `value` key in all paths automatically, but I'm still curious if there is a way to redefine value in binding?

Or does value declared through `Binding` in groovy becomes mutable?

**UPDATE:**
`bean` is a hash map with hardcoded configs. It may be just an empty map.
What basically I'm doing is injecting there more maps with value at the end.

If I have a chain of values:

- `"config.some.var" = 10`
- `"config.some.var2" = 20`
- `"config.some.var.more" = 30`

Will result in:

```
[config: [
    some: [
        var: 10,
        var2: 20
    ]
]]
```

The latest as expected will be discarded, as it has already a value of `10`. What I want is to override the first value with latest, while preserving all other values on the same level of depth.

The code above produce the following:

```
def bean = [someOtherConfig: []]
convert bean, 'config.var', 10
convert bean, 'config.var2', 20
convert bean, 'config.var.more', 30
assert bean == [someOtherConfig: [], config: [var: 10, var2: 20]]
```

Comment: Can you supply an example that runs, but doesn't work as you want?  I cannot run the above sample as I don't know what `bean` should be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see from your question what you're trying to do, but this gives you the output you say you'd expect from the input you describe:

```
def build = { name ->
  name.split( /\./ ).reverse().inject( [:] ) { m, n ->
    [ (n): m ]
  }
}

def map = build( 'some.config.value' )

assert map == ['some':['config':['value':[:]]]]
```

You can also do interesting things like this by playing with Closure delegates:

```
def map = new ConfigBuilder().build {
  config.some.var = 10
  config.some.var2 = 20
  config.some.var.more = 30
}

assert map == [config:[some:[var:10, var2:20]]]

// Implementation

class ConfigBuilder {
  private Map map, curr
  private boolean ignore = false

  ConfigBuilder( Map initial=[:] ) {
    this.map = initial
    this.curr = this.map
  }

  def build( Closure c ) {
    c.delegate = this
    c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    c()
    map
  }

  def propertyMissing( String name ) {
    if( ignore ) return this 
    if( curr[ name ] == null ) {
      curr[ name ] = [:]
      curr = curr[ name ]
    }
    else if( curr[ name ] instanceof Map ) {
      curr = curr[ name ]
    }
    else {
      ignore = true
    }
    this
  }

  void setProperty( String name, value ) {
    if( !ignore ) {
      curr[ name ] = value
    }
    // Reset and go again
    ignore = false
    curr = map
    value
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have updated my question, but meanwhile will try to tweak with your sample.

Comment: @liaant Have you looked into [using `ConfigSlurper`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html)?  It doesn't take defaults, and will throw an exception on re-assignement, but it might also help.

Comment: @liaant posted an update to my answer... Not hugely tested, but might be of interest...

Comment: this happens to be almost what I was expecting. Thanks for additional food for brains. I'll handle from here, thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to make the binding of key to value mutable but you should be able to get almost the same effect with a single mutable value that you bind only once.